# How to Print Square box (only outline) in java using if conditions and only one for loop (i used two for loops)

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Square1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int size = input.nextInt();
        for (int row = 0;row < size; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < size; col++) {
                if (row == 0) { System.out.print('-'); }
                else if (col == 0) { System.out.print('|'); }
                else if (col == (size-1))  { System.out.print('|'); }
                else if (row == (size-1))  { System.out.print('-'); }
                else { System.out.print(' '); }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

o/p :

4

```
----
|  |
|  |
----
```

But I need o/p as

given size = 4

```
----
|  |
|  |
|  |
|  |
----
```

Please provide and answer.

Comment: Why do you think using 1 loop is better than two?

Comment: my guide gives task to print square box using only one for loop..
but i used 2 for loops, and o/p is not correct as given by my guide..
i need o/p as 
if given size = 4
----
|  |
|  |
|  |
|  |
----

Comment: You can keep both `row` and `col` as index and manage their values in one loop. Normal iteration: increment `col`, special iteration on full row increment `row`, reset `col` and do a `println()`

Answer (score 0):

Go with squared size `for(int i=0;i<size * size;i++)` and recalculate row and column by dividing squared size with size:

```
    int row = i / size;
    int col = i % size;
```

code will be:

```
public static void main(String args[]){

        int size=4;
        for(int i=0;i<size * size;i++)
        {
                int row = i / size;
                int col = i % size;


                if(row==0 && col < size-1) { System.out.print('*'); }
                else if(col==0) { System.out.print('*'); }
                else if(col==(size-1))  { System.out.println('*'); }
                else if(row==(size-1))  { System.out.print('*'); }
                else { System.out.print(' '); }
        }
}
```